# Test suite for verifying C-style operator precedence and associativity

Tags: compiler-construction, operator-precedence

I am writing a byte code compiler for a toy language to get a better understanding of the techniques involved. The language I am implementing has essentially the same precedence and associativity rules as C for arithmetic and relational operators.

I have searched unsuccessfully for a test suite, set of example expressions, or similar that I could use to verify that I have implemented things correctly.

Of course, I can create my own set of test expressions but am concerned that it won't be very thorough. Any suggestions?